# Send Parent URL of an iframe via mail (PHP)

Tags: javascript, php, iframe

I have a feedback form as standard at the bottom of my webpages. It is included by iframe. Now I  want to get the contents of the feedback in the emails sent from the form and also the URL of the page the feedback is about. What I have been able to do is get the URL from the parent page into the iframe using `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`. What I am not able to do is to get the form to include the URL in the text of the email sent.

Here is the code of the form:

```
 <form class="box" action="auswerten.php" method="post">
 <div class="label cell">War die Information auf dieser Seite hilfreich?</div><br>
 <p> <input style="clear:left" type="radio" name="auswahl" value="ja">
 Ja &nbsp; &nbsp;
  <input type="radio" name="auswahl" value="nein">
  Nein &nbsp; &nbsp;
  <input type="radio" name="auswahl" value="notfound">
  Enthielt nicht, was ich gesucht habe.
  <br><br><br></p>   
  <div class="input"><input value="Abschicken" name="submit" type="submit"></div>
  </form>
```

Here is the code for the script called when the form is sent:

```
<?php
switch($_POST['auswahl']) {
    case ja:
        echo 'Das freut uns!';
        break;

    case nein:
        echo 'Das tut uns leid. Warum nicht?'; 
        include ("negativ.php");
        break;

    case notfound:
        echo 'Das tut uns leid. Was haben Sie gesucht?';
        include ("negativ.php");
        break;

    default:
        echo 'Danke für Ihr Feedback!';
}

$empfaenger = "myemail";
$betreff = "Feedback";
mail($empfaenger, $betreff, $_POST['auswahl'],$_POST['kommentar']);
?>
```

I have red various threads on here and tried various ways to include the URL as a variable I can get into the mail text (I also tried javaScript although I'd rather use php), but failed. So does anyone know of a way to do this? I would take a solution in javaScript if that's easier to do but would like one in php better. I know iframes are considered dirty but I thought using one was the smartest way to include the form. If anyone knows of a smarter way to include such a form I would be happy to hear about that as well.

Comment: I am not sure what you are doing in your other scripts but here you can use a hidden input element whose value="javascript:parent.document.URL" and then you can get it using $_POST super global Array

Comment: Thank you for the idea - but it doesn't work - URL is still not being sent. I included  <input type="hidden" name="url"  value="javascript:parent.document.URL"> into my form and $_POST['url'] into my mail function. But still no URL in the mailtext. Am I getting something wrong?

Comment: "javascript:parent.document.URL" replace this with some hardcode value and see if its included or not ?

Comment: It's not included. So probably a problem with my form.

Comment: I got it to work now with the hardcore value by putting the hidden field to the beginning of the form. But it still doesn't work with the javascript as value.

Comment: Get it work for you ;) you got the idea now do some work